# Generic type in interface throwing error in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to access stored properties, the accessed property might be `null` if it has no value. I wanted to create a generic type which would provide me with the option to define the type of the stored property, in case its value is defined.

```
type DefinedValue = string | number | number[] | boolean;

type Value = DefinedValue | null;

interface Store {
    get: <TruthyType extends DefinedValue>(key: string) => TruthyType | null;
}

const state: any = {};

const store: Store = {
    get: (key: string) => state.properties[key] as Value,
};
```

When I try to use the code above, TS compiler throws this error:

```
Type '(key: string) => Value' is not assignable to type '<TruthyType extends DefinedValue>(key: string) => TruthyType | null'.
  Type 'Value' is not assignable to type 'TruthyType | null'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TruthyType | null'.
```

Link to [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdhAJgNQIYBsCu0AvFAM7ABOKA5lAD5TJ4C2ARhOXQ82%20QNoC6nFgHthOCFmQBuAFAzQkKNnxFYCFOmUFOjHDlkyUwdvCwBjaAGVgw8tADeMqM6hUIwAFxQAPABVyeMAAFiC%204NAQAB7GyGgkakiomLgEAHwAFADWECBeZJTIVACUUISpUP6BIWGK9Lr6MgC%20cmbCyGSkwFjGXpIgpVD2jQat7cCdthBe1pMDji6u7l5ZOXkU1CVlnd0QAHRg5MKQ5MCIECS82SCCWPFaEAA0TVJAA)

Comment: Question is very unclear to me. And properties that have no value are `undefined`, not `null`... And why do you need the `as Value` type assertion?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I guess he wants to use null for inexistent properties, instead of undefined. Also the generics just allow him to avoid casts when calling the `get` function, which is dirty code, but kinda smart

Comment: Why do you need `Store.get` to be generic? Why not `get: (key: string) => Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided code, in the `const store` constant, you define the `get` method. The problem is that the `get` method you define is not generic, but the `Store` interface requires a generic `get` method.

The solution is to define the `store.get` method as generic:

```
const store: Store = {
    get: <T extends DefinedValue>(key: string) => state[key] as T | null,
};
```

Still, if the `state` object doesn't contain a `key` property, `undefined` will be returned, instead of `null`. To fix this, you can implement a check whether or not the property exists:

```
get: <T extends DefinedValue>(key: string) => {
    if (Object.keys(state).includes(key)) return state[key] as T;
    else return null;
}
```

This will never return `undefined`, instead, will return `null` if the property doesn't exists, or if `state` contains such property, but its value is `null`.

Another issue with your code is that the `state` constant is just an object, containing anything (DOM elements, numbers, nulls, XmlHttpRequests, etc.). TypeScript allows you to type properties with any name in the following way:

```
const state: { [name: string]: Value } = {};
```

This will tell TypeScript that all properties inside of `state` are of type `Value`. Note that the key type may be only `string` or `number` (as far as I know).

Finally, it isn't a good OOP practice to have global constants. If you want to do it in your own way, ignore the following suggestion.

You should make the `store` constant a class instead:

```
class MyStore implements Store {
    public readonly INSTANCE = new MyStore();
    private _state: { [name: string]: Value } = {};
    public get <T extends DefinedValue>(key: string) {
        if (Object.keys(this._state).includes(key)) return this._state[key] as T;
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the original code, the `state` variable is properly defined, I wanted to simplify the code to focus only on the error itself but thanks anyway.

Comment: @TomášKudláč you're welcome, thanks for going the extra mile to provide a minimal reproducible example